# Issue with JavaLoader while loading jsoup

Tags: java, coldfusion, jsoup

I am trying to load [jsoup](http://jsoup.org) using [JavaLoader](http://javaloader.riaforge.org/) but I am getting an initiation error:

```
<cfscript>
// An Array with absolute file paths of the referred jar files.
paths = expandPath("jars/jsoup-1.7.3.jar");
//Creating a java loader object by passing in the array containing the file paths -
loaderObj =createObject("component","javaloader.JavaLoader").init([expandPath('jars/jsoup-1.7.3.jar')]);
//So now, we can simply create a instance of an object from the 'bmw' and 'pulsar' class.
writedump(loaderObj);
abort;
jsoup = loaderObj.create("org.jsoup.Jsoup");
</cfscript>
```

> Object Instantiation Exception.
>   Class not found: org.jsoup.Jsoup

Answer (score 1):

The error *"Class not found"* means that Javaloader could not find the requested class.

This suggests that `expandPath('jars/jsoup-1.7.3.jar')` is not resolving to the correct location for that file.

To see where it is looking, just dump it out:

```
writeDump( expandPath('jars/jsoup-1.7.3.jar') );
```

That will tell you where JavaLoader is being told to look, so you can then either move the existing jsoup jar file to that location, or update the path to point to where the jar file currently is.

Depending on your application, you may find it useful to setup `/jars` as a mapping, so you can refer to `/jars/jsoup-1.7.3.jar` and know that the mapping will be used to resolve the path.

Comment: Path is correct and even i dumped this `writedump(loaderObj);`, I see the methods which are there for javaloader. But it is not picking jsoup

Comment: If the path is definitely correct then make sure the user which CF is running as has permissions for that file.

Comment: i am running on local, so i think the issue is with the org.jsoup.Jsoup

Comment: The error "Class not found" means that Javaloader could not find the requested class. Since "org.jsoup.Jsoup" is the correct class name, the issue is that JavaLoader can't access the jar file - either due to permissions or because the file isn't there.